# MongoDB verbose logging. What does every v add to output?

Tags: mongodb, logging

What does every 'v' (from one to five) add to log output?

Sure, I can experiment. But does anybody provide a concrete answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a prescriptive list of what log lines each level of verbosity adds. Most of the extra details are really only meaningful for the MongoDB developers (particularly as the log levels increase).

You can grep the log entries [from the source code](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo) if you're curious.

For example to see what's logged at level 1:

```
$ grep -r "LOG(1)" * | wc -l
185

$ grep -r "LOG(1)" * | head
client/connpool.cpp:                LOG(1) << "Exception thrown when checking pooled connection to " <<
client/dbclient.cpp:            LOG(1) << "creating new connection to:" << _servers[0] << endl;
client/dbclient.cpp:            LOG(1) << "connected connection!" << endl;
client/dbclient_rs.cpp:                    LOG(1) << "checking replica set: " << name << endl;
client/dbclient_rs.cpp:            if( wasFound ){ LOG(1) << "slave '" << prev << ( wasMaster ? "' is master node, trying to find another node" :
client/dbclient_rs.cpp:            else{ LOG(1) << "slave '" << prev << "' was not found in the replica set" << endl; }
client/dbclient_rs.cpp:        else LOG(1) << "slave '" << prev << "' is not initialized or invalid" << endl;
client/dbclient_rs.cpp:            LOG(1) << "dbclient_rs getSlave falling back to a non-local secondary node" << endl;
client/dbclient_rs.cpp:        LOG(1) << "dbclient_rs getSlave no member in secondary state found, "
client/dbclient_rs.cpp:        LOG(1) <<  "_check : " << getServerAddress() << endl;
```

Comment: What kind of logs stored for the level 1.Which level is for logging the Error?

Comment: @SooryaPrakash This answer refers to a relatively old version of MongoDB (it was posted in Dec-2013). The logging options and granularity have changed significantly since then, so I would refer to the documentation relevant to your version of MongoDB. Log messages in MongoDB 3.0+ are categorised by severity and component so you have more control over the types of messages that are logged: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/log-messages/. The default logging level is sufficient for common usage & diagnostics; I would only increase temporarily for troubleshooting purposes.